# how to restart the music player after play a sound in my app in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

Using AVAudioPlayer when play my sound the music player in background is stopped and when my sound finish the music player not resume, how can i resume the music player?

Comment: Do you have your own music player or Native one?

Comment: Native music player app

Comment: This may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549756/how-to-pause-and-resume-same-song-in-iphone-sdk-using-avaudioplayer

Comment: Sorry but i not understand how can i resume the track of the native music player app that playing before my sound play

Comment: So just to clarify, is your music player playing a sound, then it is stopped so that a 2nd sound can be played? If so, are you using an AVAudioPlayer to play both sounds (or 2 AVAudioPlayers)?

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController () <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ttt" ofType:@"mp3"]] error:nil];
_audioPlayer.delegate = self;
}

- (void)play:(id)sender
{
    [_audioPlayer play];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![audioSession setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"resume music player failed, error=%@", error);
    }
}

@end
```